# Rails Getting Started Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a newbie in rails, and I've been looking all over for an answer for this issue. Here's what I have:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
```

Now I want to list all the items with their properties and the book associated with them. They would go under index in the items_controller.rb

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /items
  # GET /items.xml
  def index
    @items = Item.all
```

now how would I handle books in the ItemsController so I can list them in index.html.erb keeping in mind that an item belongs to only one book? if I add:

```
@books = items.book.find
```

right under @items = Item.all so I can reference them in the index.html.erb I get:

undefined method 'book' for #`<Array:0x10427f998`>

I have a feeling that the answer is so simple but so far I haven't figured it out. Is there any tutorial that you guys are aware of that covers this matter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your view, when you iterate over all of your `@items`, just reference the book for each one.  Example ERB (`app/views/items/index.html.erb`):

```
<% @items.each do |item| -%>
  Item: <%= item.name %>
  Book: <%= item.book.title %>
<% end -%>
```

---

If instead your intention is to display each book with the associated items under each book, you'd be better off using the `index` action on the `BooksController`.  Find all the books, iterate over each book, and for each book, iterate over the items for that book.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also had some bad data that cause some of the problems, but this totally works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The array of items doesn't have a book, each individual item does. It looks like you're trying to get the book of ALL the items, which doesn't exist.

Try `@items[0].book` or using a loop in your view:

```
<ul>
<% for item in @items %>
  <li><%= item.book.title %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

You could also use a partial to iterate through the array. See the section "Rendering a collection of partials" at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `items.book` on an array of items, and the array doesn't have a method named `book` (hence the error).  You'd need to get a single book from that array (such as `items[0]`), then call `.book` on that.